# Problema Query Beego

Tags: postgresql, golang

Estou tendo problemas para montar uma Query em Go, usando o framework Beego.

Erro:

> 2018/12/20 09:21:32.104 [C] [asm_amd64.s:522]  Handler crashed with error runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
>   2018/12/20 09:21:32.104 [C] [asm_amd64.s:522]  C:/Go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:522
>   2018/12/20 09:21:32.104 [C] [asm_amd64.s:522]  C:/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:513
>   2018/12/20 09:21:32.104 [C] [asm_amd64.s:522]  C:/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:82
>   2018/12/20 09:21:32.104 [C] [asm_amd64.s:522]  C:/Go/src/runtime/signal_windows.go:204
>   2018/12/20 09:21:32.105 [C] [asm_amd64.s:522]  C:/Users/joao/go/src/hello/controllers/cidades.go:35
>   2018/12/20 09:21:32.109 [C] [asm_amd64.s:522]  C:/Users/joao/go/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/router.go:834
>   2018/12/20 09:21:32.110 [C] [asm_amd64.s:522]  C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2741
>   2018/12/20 09:21:32.110 [C] [asm_amd64.s:522]  C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1847
>   2018/12/20 09:21:32.111 [C] [asm_amd64.s:522]  C:/Go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333
>   2018/12/20 09:21:32.111 [server.go:2977]  [HTTP] http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls

Controller:

```
package controllers

import (
    "hello/models"

    "github.com/astaxie/beego"
    "github.com/astaxie/beego/orm"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

type CidadesController struct {
    beego.Controller
}

func init() {
    beego.BConfig.WebConfig.AutoRender = false
    orm.RegisterDriver("postgres", orm.DRPostgres)
    orm.RegisterDataBase("default", "User", "postgres:senha@/nomeDoDB? 
    charset=utf8", 30)
}

func (this *CidadesController) Get() {

    var cidade []models.Cidade

    cidades, err := orm.NewQueryBuilder("postgres")

    if err != nil {
        //
    }

    cidades.Select("cid_codigo",
        "cid_nome").
        From("ger_cidade").
        Limit(10).
        Offset(0)

    sql := cidades.String()

    o := orm.NewOrm()
    o.Raw(sql, 20).QueryRows(&cidade)
}
```

Model:

```
package models

import (
    "github.com/astaxie/beego/orm"
)

type Cidade struct {
    Id   int    `db:"cid_codigo"`
    Name string `db:"cid_nome"`
}

func init() {
    orm.RegisterModel(new(Cidade))
}
```

Pelo o que eu entendi está voltando um `err` na Query, mas como eu não estou tratando está dando esse erro. O que eu não entendo é porque volta erro na query? Pelo o que eu consegui entender está tudo certo.

**RESOLVIDO**

Não dá pra usar QueryBuilder com Postgres, tem que ser em Raw

Comment: Coloque a solução que você encontrou como uma resposta , senão me engano tem a opção de você responder a própria pergunta dessa maneira você facilita que outras pessoas achem a solução.

Comment: Show, já respondo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No framework Beego não é possível utilizar o `QueryBuilder` com `PgSql`, só com `MySql`. Então ficou assim:

**No Controller:**

```
package controllers

import (
    "fmt"
    "hello/models"

    "github.com/astaxie/beego"
    "github.com/astaxie/beego/orm"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

type CidadesController struct {
    beego.Controller
}

func init() {
    beego.BConfig.WebConfig.AutoRender = false
    orm.RegisterDriver("postgres", orm.DRPostgres)
    orm.RegisterDataBase("default", "postgres", "dbname=nomeDoDB host=localhost 
user=user password=senhaDoDb port=5432 sslmode=disable", 30)
}

func (this *CidadesController) Get() {

    o := orm.NewOrm()
    o.Using("default")

    var cidade []models.Cidade

    res, err := o.Raw("SELECT cid_codigo as id, cid_nome, est_codigo FROM 
    geral.ger_cidade").QueryRows(&cidade)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    if res == 0 {
        fmt.Println("Sem registros")
        return
    }

    this.Data["json"] = &cidade
    this.ServeJSON()
}
```

**No Model:**

```
package models

import (
    "github.com/astaxie/beego/orm"
)

type Cidade struct {
    Id         int    `json:"id" db:"nomeDoCampoNoDB"`
    Cid_nome   string `json:"name" db:"nomeDoCampoNoDB"`
    Est_codigo int    `json:"codigo_estado" db:"nomeDoCampoNoDB"`
}

func init() {
    orm.RegisterModel(new(Cidade))
}
```

Utilizei `sql` "puro" pra fazer a Query. No meu ponto de vista, não está bem explicito na documentação que eu não posso utilizar o `QueryBuilder` com `PgSql`. Se alguém quiser dar uma olhada na documentação onde fala sobre `QueryBuilder` aqui está o link: https://beego.me/docs/mvc/model/querybuilder.md